# Cannot get data from JSON API

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I want to get data from this endpoint. But when I start this code, I have these things on console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw3Ik.png)

```
componentDidMount(){
fetch('https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/movies/top-movies/all/10/explicit.json', {mode: 'no-cors'})
  .then(res => console.log('dsdd',res))
  .catch(err => console.log('error', err))}
```

Comment: That API doesn't have CORS enabled, so the browser stops you from reading that data. You could e.g. create a server of your own and proxy the request. More [info here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using create-react-app? It comes with http-proxy-middleware to make back-end requests. You should use proxy: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development. In the package.json, add this:

`"proxy": "https://rss.itunes.apple.com"`

Then modify your fetch URL to be

```
fetch('/api/v1/us/movies/top-movies/all/10/explicit.json')
  .then(res => console.log('dsdd',res))
  .catch(err => console.log('error', err))}
```

If you are not using CRA, the link I shared has got instructions about how you can set it up yourself to leverage http-proxy-middleware's features.